# How to cut/split image into pieces [PHP]

Tags: php, image

I tried to create something like [this site](https://www.imgonline.com.ua/eng/cut-photo-into-pieces.php) do (slice image into pieces)

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('a.jpg');
$height = imagesy($im);
$width = imagesx($im);

$a = 20;
while($a<=$height){
    $slice[] = $a;
    $a+=20;
}
if($a>$height && end($slice) !== $height){
    $slice[] = $a+($height-$a);
}

for($i=0;$i<count($slice);$i++){
    $im2 = imagecrop($im, ['x' => 0, 'y' => 0, 'width' => $width, 'height' => $slice[$i]]);
    if ($im2 !== FALSE) {
        imagejpeg($im2, "test/example-$i.jpg");
        imagedestroy($im2);
    }
}
imagedestroy($im);
echo PHP_EOL .'Fck Yeah'. PHP_EOL;
?>
```

i wanted to slice image every 20 pixel verticaly, but code above only work on the first only :'(
[image: screenshot]

Thanks

Comment: Your "this site" link seems to be wrong? Did you mean: https://www.imgonline.com.ua/eng/cut-photo-into-pieces.php ?

Comment: @KIKO Software edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace

```
$im2 = imagecrop($im, ['x' => 0, 'y' => 0, 'width' => $width, 'height' => $slice[$i]]);
```

with

```
$im2 = imagecrop($im, ['x' => 0, 'y' => $slice[$i] * $i, 'width' => $width, 'height' => $slice[$i]])
```

**Here is the magic**: Your Y axis must be updated each time your loop runs. In your code, Y is always 0. That's why every time you crop a portion, it starts from the top of the main image. By replacing Y static value, Y dynamically changes each time and each image portion's Y axis starts from where the previous cropped portion was cut off.

Comment: Why? Please edit and explain how this new code solves the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Inside imagecrop function the `y` coordinate is always set to 0. Hence while looping the image is cropped from initial coordinate `y=0` to `$slice[$i]`

I would suggest to user following for loop instead:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($slice);$i++){
    $im2 = imagecrop($im, ['x' => 0, 'y' => $slice[$i] - $a, 'width' => $width, 'height' => $slice[$i]]);
    if ($im2 !== FALSE) {
        imagejpeg($im2, "test/example-$i.jpg");
        imagedestroy($im2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the height, you should be changing the y value

```
...
$a = 0;
while($a<=$height){
    $slice[] = $a;
    $a+=20;
}
if($a>$height && end($slice) !== $height){
    $slice[] = $a+($height-$a);
}
for($i=0;$i<count($slice);$i++){
    $im2 = imagecrop($im, ['x' => 0, 'y' => $slice[$i], 'width' => $width, 'height' => 20);
    if ($im2 !== FALSE) {
        imagejpeg($im2, "test/example-$i.jpg");
        imagedestroy($im2);
    }
}
...
```